# Macro to send multiple files to multiple address

Tags: vba, excel, email

Please help!! I need advice or info to help me complete this time consuming task.

Every month I have to download 30 files from an internal database, saving them in that months file path. e.g. June files in June's file path. I then have to send these to the 30 different customers to who they relate on a generic email.

e.g AA customers workbook to AA email address. All customer information and codes are saved on another workbook.

I want to do this by a macro but only have the skills to install a macro on each spread sheet and then have to enter the workbook and run them individually (still time consuming). I was hoping somebody would be able to point me in the direction of being able to run one macro that send all the files in one folder to the relevant customer or would point me to something similar which can help me get started.

Thanks

Code:

```
Sub Mail_Workbook_1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "bradley.johns@xxxx.net"
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "Monthly Japan Order"
        .Body = "Good Morning,Please find this month's JPN order sheet attached."
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you put on every single sheet, can you put that on the question? so I can have better understanding what you are trying to do

Comment: Please put code in body of question.  Someone downvoted you (not me) probably because of that.  To format the code use an indentation, best to indent whilst still in VBA IDE rather than StackOverflow question editing box.

Comment: No problem, Im learning and new to this site so prepared to take a few hits :)

Comment: Are all the files to be found in one folder?

Comment: Yeah that is correct. but this file path will change as the months do. So all June file will be in June folder and when we move to July they will all be in a separate folder marked July. all the workbooks are distinguished by two alphabetical characters. e.g aa,ab,ah,de etc..

Comment: The master folder they will be n will be under 2015. H:\Departments\01 GPPD Department - New\VV Customers\"2016"\"June" - ""changeable by month and year

Comment: I've edited answer, added some code to demonstrate how to cycle through files in a folder.  You'll need to add reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: And edited again, .... the code now takes into account some of the business logic you have mentioned, so moveable month and year and also two character filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to create a Master.xlsm file to process the emails.
It should contain two worksheets, [Settings] and [Email List].

Worksheet [Settings]:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦   ¦ A              ¦ B                                                               ¦
¦---+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------¦
¦ 1 ¦ Folder Path    ¦ C:\Report\2016\June                                             ¦
¦---+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------¦
¦ 2 ¦ File Extension ¦ xls                                                             ¦
¦---+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------¦
¦ 3 ¦ Subject        ¦ Monthly Japan Order                                             ¦
¦---+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------¦
¦ 4 ¦ Body           ¦ Good Morning,Please find this month's JPN order sheet attached. ¦
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Worksheet [Email List]: Column A should have no blank entries

```
+----------------------------------------------+
¦   ¦ A                       ¦ B              ¦
¦---+-------------------------+----------------¦
¦ 1 ¦ To                      ¦ File Base Name ¦
¦---+-------------------------+----------------¦
¦ 2 ¦ bradley.johns@xxxx.net  ¦ bj             ¦
¦---+-------------------------+----------------¦
¦ 3 ¦ bradley.adrian@xxxx.net ¦ aa             ¦
¦---+-------------------------+----------------¦
¦ 4 ¦ frank.johns@xxxx.net    ¦ ab             ¦
¦---+-------------------------+----------------¦
¦ 5 ¦ trump.donals@xxxx.net   ¦ ac             ¦
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Paste this code in a public module.  When your run ProcessFiles() it should iterate through your email list and send out your emails.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcessFiles()
    'Setup Outlook
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim rowCount As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim fileName As String, emailTo As String
    With Worksheets("Email List")
        rowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1))

        For i = 2 To rowCount
            emailTo = .Cells(i, 1)
            fileName = getFileName(.Cells(i, 2))
            If Len(Dir(fileName)) Then SendMail emailTo, fileName, OutApp
        Next
    End With

    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function getFileName(fileBaseName As String)
    Dim folderPath As String, fileExtension As String, fileName As String
    folderPath = Range("Settings!B1")
    fileExtension = Range("Settings!B2")

    If Left(fileExtension, 1) <> "." Then fileExtension = "." & fileExtension
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"

    getFileName = folderPath & fileBaseName & fileExtension

End Function

Public Sub SendMail(emailTo As String, fileName As String, OutApp As Object)
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = emailTo
        .CC = ""
        .subject = Range("Settings!B3")
        .body = Range("Settings!B4")
        .Attachments.Add fileName
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! I nearly seem to have this working, however its sending the email to cusomerbradlejohns@xxx.net. I am just trying to figure out how to remove the customer part of the email address and from where.

Comment: I had an typo in emailTo = getFileName(.Cells(i, 1)).  It should read  emailTo = .Cells(i, 1).  Sorry about that I couldn't test the send email I don't have Outlook setup.

Comment: That works great now. Thank you very much for your time. If there is anyway I can help you by giving feedback please let me know. Like I said I'm new to this site and its requirements.

Comment: Accepting my answer was enough it helps me build my reputation.  I just joined yesterday and I can't use many of the features because my reputation isn't high enough.

Answer (score 1):

(Better information given) ... sounds like you need to step up from VBA Macro Recorder code.  You'll need to master referencing workbooks and worksheets with variables instead of relying upon ActiveWorkbook and ActiveSheet which come from macro recorder.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()

    '* Specify wb instead of ActiveWorkbook
    '* Here's how to open a file

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\bbc.txt")

    '* Specify sheet instead of activesheet

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    '* in your macro code replace activeworkbook with wb
    '* in your macro code replace activesheet with ws

End Sub

'* Tools ->References -> Microsoft Sscripting Runtime

Private Sub ToCycleThroughFiles()

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Dim sTodaysYear As String
    sTodaysYear = Format(Now(), "yyyy")

    Dim sTodaysMonth As String
    sTodaysMonth = Format(Now(), "mmmm")

    Dim sFolder As String
    sFolder = "H:\Departments\01 GPPD Department - New\VV Customers\" & sTodaysYear & "\" & sTodaysMonth


    Dim fld As Scripting.Folder
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)

    Dim filLoop As Scripting.File
    For Each filLoop In fld.Files

        If InStr(1, filLoop.Name, ".xls", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            '* only interested in excel files,  xls, xlsm etc.

            Dim vSplitFileName As Variant
            vSplitFileName = VBA.Split(filLoop.Name, ".")
            If Len(vSplitFileName(0)) = 2 Then
                '* two character named workbook, e.g. aa.xls, ab.xls,  ah.xls,  de.xls
                Call SubRoutine(filLoop.Path)
            End If

        End If

    Next filLoop

End Sub

Private Sub SubRoutine(ByVal sWorkbookFullFileName As String)

    '* Do your stuff for each workbook here
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sWorkbookFullFileName)

    '....
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting @S Meaden, I need all the help I can get as fairly new to me. This is the macro I use in each work book at present;

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience. Would I paste this in the first work book in order to run for all? or should I paste this in a separate workbook? Do I place the macro I have already created in "*Do your stuff here" If so how would I get it to send to different email address for each file or would It mean running the individual macro in each file. Thanks